# how to configure the Bigcommerec api

Tags: php, api, bigcommerce

In bigcommerce site I want functionality like anonymous users can upload image for products which he wants to purchase and add to cart.Like this (http://www.woowoonails.com/) site.

When you will open this link you will see Design Your Own Nail Wraps! container on home containing link user your own photos when you will click on this you will be on this link (http://www.woowoonails.com/designer/layout).Here you can upload your photos and click on add to bag. Same functionality I want on my site but I did not get any idea.Bigcommerce team does now allow to upload php file  to their server.Then I tried to use api.

But I am not able to configure it.I have downloaded the api from (github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php) .But I am not getting idea how to configure it and use.

I have also download the single php file(raw.github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php/master/bigcommerce.php) and put it inside the Bigcommerce1 folder and then include in  my file containing code:

```
require 'Bigcommerce1/bigcommerce.php';
BigCommerce_Api::configure(array(
    'store_url' => 'siteurl',
    'username'  => 'admin',
    'api_key'   => 'df38dd10e9665a3cfa667817d78ec91ee9384bc3'
));
```

But nothing work.Can you give me some light about how can I achieve the functionality to upload photos and also about api configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the FTP not the BigCommerce API to capture the image... BigCommerce does support file uploading, but from what I have read it is an afterthought and is not configurable via the API. It is easier therefore to have an iframe for file upload, capturing the file contents and uploading it to the bigC (s)FTP server for storage...

This means you could post a file to any other site (so hosted externally) upload it to the FTP under some unique id, and when the order was submitted re-join the two.

Also to connect to the BigCommerce API, it is best to write or use a wrapper function library around BigCommerce

so for example we made the library object-based due to errors and undesirable functionality in the PHP version of the API, and a difference in coding styles, so we just use the following to get all orders 'Awaiting Fulfillment' and work from there...

```
$bcAPI = new bigcommerceAPI();
$orders = $bcAPI->getOrders(); 
$orders = array_filter($orders,function($data){ if($data->status == 'Awaiting Fulfillment'){ return true; } return false; });
```